# Use 32bit COM Server from a 64bit .NET Program

Tags: .net, com, interop, 32bit-64bit

I'm having some trouble with COM Interop, the situation is as follows:

A 32-Bit COM Exe Server (that was programmed in C++) offers a class with some member functions that deal with 3rd party hardware (This hardware also ties the COM Exe Server to 32-Bit, since the manufacturer doesn't support 64-Bit).

I want to use the 32-Bit COM Exe Server in a 64-Bit .NET (C#) Application... At first I tried to add a reference to the Exe Server in Visual Studio 2010 and it created an Interop-DLL. This Interop-DLL provided me with the necessary functions, one of them being declared as:

```
int Initialize(ref string callingApplicationPath);
```

The original declaration in C++ looks like this:

```
LONG Class::Initialize(BSTR* callingApplicationPath)
```

...and like this in IDL:

```
[id(1)] LONG Initialize([in] BSTR* callingApplicationPath);
```

However, when I want to call this function from C# via the Interop-DLL, it throws a BadImageFormatException. Looks like the Interop-DLL is a 32-Bit DLL (Maybe there's a possibility to generate a 64-Bit-DLL?).

My next attempt was to instantiate the Exe Server with this code:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("OurCompany.Class");
Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
Object[] args = { Marshal.StringToBSTR(str) };
Object result = type.InvokeMember("Initialize", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, o, args);
```

This code, on the other hand, throws a TargetInvocationException (More specifically: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)) at my head. Unfortunately I was unable to find out what type I have to pass in to the function from C#... I tried all the StringToXXX-functions in the Marshal-class but nothing seems to work :/ I guess I'm missing something simple here, but I don't see what.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Best Regards

Christian

Comment: Have you tried to fire up Process Monitor and look what's going on when instantiation is done? Maybe it doesn't find some registry entries, or some process has insufficient rights? Process Monitor migt help with that.

Comment: @sharptooth: The instantiation itself works fine and I can successfully call a Dummy-method that takes no arguments and returns an int. The problem is "just" the System.String -> BSTR* conversion

Comment: I see. What's the point of passing BSTR* as an "in" parameter? Why not just BSTR?

Comment: My colleague is in charge of the COM Exe server and told me that the IDL function declarations were generated automatically. I'm no expert in IDL myself, but could I just leave out the "in"-modifier?

Comment: I'm not sure about omitting "in", but it's very strange to see such declaration in IDL. The usual way is to just pass BSTR - then `string` marshalls to it without any effort.

Comment: Hm, I don't know enough about IDL to judge that, but I found this in MSDN: "The [in] attribute is applied to a parameter by default when no directional parameter attribute is specified." :S

Comment: @Christian: Okay, but using `BSTR*` as an "in" parameter looks really strange.

Comment: @sharptooth: All right, I'll check up with my colleague to see if we can change the IDL-declaration to [id(1)] LONG Initialize(BSTR callingApplicationPath);
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @sharptooth: That did the trick, thanks a lot! If you'll answer to the question, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDL declaration

```
[id(1)] LONG Initialize([in] BSTR* str);
```

makes no sense. When you pass a `BSTR` as an `in` parameter just pass it "by value":

```
[id(1)] LONG Initialize([in] BSTR str);
```

then you will not need to do anything special in C# code - just pass `string` there and marshalling will be done automatically.

Of course you'll have to change the method implementation signature as well.

Answer (score 1):

By default, .NET strings are marshalled by COM Interop to LPTSTR in C++. Thus you have to explicitly marshal any other type of unmanaged string (including BSTR) to and from a .NET string using the MarshalAs attribute.
Try

```
 int Initialize([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] ref string callingApplicationPath);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how would I incorprate this code into my C# program? In the last code sample in my question I don't declare any function signatures, but instead use InvokeMember. The very first line of code in my question was taken from the automatically generated Interop.DLL.

Comment: I would change the automatically generated Interop.DLL manually.

Comment: I checked out the generated Interop-DLL with .NET Reflector and found out that it uses the signature you provided. However, by calling the COM Exe Server through this DLL, I'm calling it in-process and that fails because my C# App is 64-Bit and the Interop-DLL + the COM Exe Server are both 32-Bit. That's why I tried to call the functions out-of-process via InvokeMember, unfortunately without success :/

Comment: Only thing you can still try is to check the size of every structure on a 32 bit machine. I had to deal with 32 vs 64 bits in the past and I found most issues when using sizeof to compare every bit. I would also change  int into int32 and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your help, even though it didn't actually solve the problem ;) Still +1 for you, since your answer gave me deeper insights.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the common language runtime used by .net there are only a few cases where you have to distinguish between 32 and 64 bit using managed code. However this is only true for the .net envoirement. If you try to access unmanaged resources the bit format matters, since all the adresses (exported interface) are quite static and not compiled for 64 bit.
Still you could uses a quite simple constuct to achive your task;
 Create a 32 bit .net wrapper and conenct it via wcf to your 64 bit application. I'd suggest creating a mixed mode c++ wrapper to your com/unmanaged server and placing a wcf based layer written in "pure" clr (c#, vb.net, etc) as the conenction point to your main application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, too... but I'd very much like to keep the numbers of layers as low as possible. And due to sharptooth's help, I managed to overcome my initial problem :)

Comment: nevermind. didn't knew you had access to the unmanaged code part aswell, since you said something about 3rd party hardware ;)